# Working with html tag "select"

Tags: jquery

html:

```
<select id="my_select" name="my_select">
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
<option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

js:

```
$("#my_select :contains('two')").first().attr("selected", "selected");
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3M9cC/)

So, the selected element should be `two`, but as you see, it's `one`. How to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you calling first()?

Comment: That jsFiddle works fine for me - the two option is selected when it loads. What browser are you using?

Comment: FOR ME fiddle IS WORKING ( latest firefox win7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.prop('selected',true)`

```
$("#my_select :contains('two')").first().prop("selected", true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Pxz5/

In the [.prop() docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) it states

> > selectedIndex, tagName, nodeName, nodeType, ownerDocument, defaultChecked, and defaultSelected should be retrieved and set with the .prop() method. Prior to jQuery 1.6, these properties were retrievable with the .attr() method, but this was not within the scope of attr. These do not have corresponding attributes and are only properties.
> >
> > Nevertheless, the most important concept to remember about the checked attribute is that it does not correspond to the checked property. The attribute actually corresponds to the defaultChecked property and should be used only to set the initial value of the checkbox. The checked attribute value does not change with the state of the checkbox, while the checked property does. Therefore, the cross-browser-compatible way to determine if a checkbox is checked is to use the property:
> >
> > The same is true for other dynamic attributes, such as selected and value.

Comment: Even though prop() is prefered in versions which support it, the end result would be `selected=""` vs `selected="selected"`. It doesn't really matter what the `selected` value is: http://jsfiddle.net/EQ8t8/ That being said, OP's code should work if this works, and vice versa.

Comment: @Johan attr only sets the default starting - not the actual property

Answer (score 2):

Use .prop() instead of .attr()

```
$("#my_select :contains('two')").first().prop("selected", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your demo works if you set `No wrap - <in body>` on jsfiddle...: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/3M9cC/8/

A cleaner solution is to use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr`, I think `first` is useless in this case so you can omit it.

Quick reference:

> The .prop() method is a convenient way to set the value of
>   properties—especially when setting multiple properties, using values
>   returned by a function, or setting values on multiple elements at
>   once. It should be used when setting selectedIndex, tagName, nodeName,
>   nodeType, ownerDocument, defaultChecked, or defaultSelected. Since
>   jQuery 1.6, these properties can no longer be set with the .attr()
>   method. They do not have corresponding attributes and are only
>   properties.
>
> Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without
>   changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the value
>   property of input elements, the disabled property of inputs and
>   buttons, or the checked property of a checkbox. The .prop() method
>   should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr()
>   method. The .val() method should be used for getting and setting
>   value.

Code:

```
$("#my_select :contains('two')").prop("selected", true);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/3M9cC/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
var text1 = 'two';
$("select option").filter(function() {
    //may want to use $.trim in here
    return $(this).text() == text1; 
}).prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just set it's value instead of trying to mess with the HTML 'selected' tag:

```
if ($("#my_select :contains('two')").length > 0) {
    $("#my_select").val(2);
}
```

A [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3M9cC/7/) for it.